# What is the most efficient way to stream optional, nested lists in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have been looking through similar questions here but none are helping me with this particular issue.

I have a complex, nested object that contains lists of lists:

```
class Container {
    private List<Foo> fooList;
}

class Foo {
    private List<Bar> barList;
}

class Bar {
    private List<Baz> bazList;
}
```

When I consume a REST api, I get back a Container object that I expect will have one and only one instance of **Baz**. Once I get to my Baz object, I need to assess a predicate.  I need to guard against nulls during my traversal.

Here's what I've tried:

```
 Optional.ofNullable(container)
                .map(Container::getFooList)
                .map(List::stream)
                .map(Stream::findFirst)
                .flatMap(Function.identity())
                .map(Foo::getBarList)
                .map(List::stream)
                .map(Stream::findFirst)
                .flatMap(Function.identity())
                .map(Bar::getBazList)
                .map(List::stream)
                .flatMap(Stream::findFirst)
                .map(Baz::getCode)
                .equals(someBaz.getCode());
```

Now, this works, but it looks terrible, and I'm thinking there has to be a better way. In particular, calling the identity function seems to be the only way I can flatMap after my findFirst calls.

How can I accomplish this more succinctly?

Comment: How about using loops instead of a stream?

Comment: Do each of the getters return an Optional of their lists?

Comment: @WJS No, the Lists themselves are not Optionals. But since the original Container object is being placed within an Optional, each successive `.map` call returns an Optional, and then any `Stream.findFirst()` calls also return an Optional, hence why I need to utilize `flatMap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the identity function at all. `.map(f).flatMap(identity)` is the same as `.flatMap(f)`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(container)
    .map(Container::getFooList)
    .map(List::stream)
    .flatMap(Stream::findFirst)
    .map(Foo::getBarList)
    .map(List::stream)
    .flatMap(Stream::findFirst)
    .map(Bar::getBazList)
    .map(List::stream)
    .flatMap(Stream::findFirst)
    .map(Baz::getCode)
    .map(x -> x.equals(someBaz.getCode()))
    .orElse(false)
```

If it is in your control, I would also suggest to make whatever is giving you the `Container` return a `Optional<Container>`, rather than having to create the `Optional<Container>` inline.

Also, since `stream` never returns null, you can omit a `map` for each `getXXXList`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(container)
    .map(Container::getFooList)
    .flatMap(x -> x.stream().findFirst())
    .map(Foo::getBarList)
    .flatMap(x -> x.stream().findFirst())
    .map(Bar::getBazList)
    .flatMap(x -> x.stream().findFirst())
    .map(Baz::getCode)
    .map(x -> x.equals(someBaz.getCode()))
    .orElse(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a small helper function makes this a lot clearer:

```
    static <T> Optional<T> getOnlyItem(List<T> ts) {
        if (ts.size() > 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Expected singleton list: " + ts);
        }
        return ts.size() == 0 ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(ts.get(0));
    }

boolean status =
        getOnlyItem(container.getFooList())
                .flatMap(foo -> getOnlyItem(foo.getBarList()))
                .flatMap(bar -> getOnlyItem(bar.getBazList()))
                .map(baz -> baz.getCode())
                .map(code -> code.equals(someBaz.getCode()))
                .orElse(false);
```